# Selenium, unable to click element on DEVOPS

Tags: c#, selenium, devops, xunit

I have FontAwesomeIcon react element on page. When I run tests locally it normally works it means it finds element and do Click action.
When I am running the same scenarious in devops tests it is not interactable.
I tried to run click action in a lot of ways but nothing works.
CODE

```
IWebElement btnSearchLocalization = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".fa-1x"));
executorEventPlace.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", btnSearchLocalization);
IWebElement btnSearchLocalization2 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".fa-1x"));

btnSearchLocalization2.Click();
```

I got a lot of other problems with interacting elements but in most of cases helped one of this two solutions:

```
executorEventPlace.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", eventPlace);
executorEventPlace.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", eventPlace);
```

How to setup devops agent correctly? How to compare it with my local computer? I also added a lot of `Thread.Sleep()` but this elements must be visible.

Edit
Initialization:

```
public static IWebDriver _driver;
 public static IWebDriver Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_driver == null)
            {
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                //options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
                //options.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
                options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
                options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
                options.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
                options.AddArgument("--incognito");

                _driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\temp\chromedriver\", options);
                //_driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), options);
            }
            return _driver;
        }
    }
```

Exception:
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
(Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.84)

Comment: Which web browser and browser version are you using on the DevOps agent? Which web driver and web driver version are you running? The browser and driver version can make a big difference in subtle ways.

Comment: Browser: Google Chrome
Browser version: 99.0.4844.84
WebDriver: Selenium.WebDriver.4.1.0 
WebDriverVersion: ChromeDriver (from given path directory) 99.0.4844.51
As I understand DevOps agent is using chrome version which is available on computer, it means the same version which I run in debug mode on this remote machine.

Comment: I would directly verify which version is being used on the build server. The weird behavior you are describing has no clear cause, but would be explained if the browser and driver versions do not match.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the code used to initialize ChromeDriver?

Comment: yes, I updated it^

Comment: Azure agent is run as a Service. Not RDP client.